# Select only two checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a checkbox list and I want that the user be able to select just two of them and I want to get the value of the selected ones. 
I tried this code
**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value={{item.name}} id={{item.name}} ng-click="toggleSelection(item.name)">
```

**JS**

```
$scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(id) {
    if(typeof $scope.firstSelectedService === 'undefined'){
    $scope.firstSelectedService=id;
    }
    else
    if(typeof $scope.secondSelectedService === 'undefined'){
    $scope.secondSelectedService=id;
    }
    else
    if($scope.firstSelectedService === id){
    window.alert("test11");
    $scope.firstSelectedService='';
    }
    else
    if($scope.secondSelectedService === id){
    window.alert("test2");
    $scope.secondSelectedService='';
    }
};
```

if the user select a third one I want to delete the old value of secondSelectedService and if he de-select a checked one, I want to delete it's value. I have a trouble when deselecting one, I don't see the alert box with "test1" or "test2", I see it only if I select the checkbox again. I only want to ask if it's a good way to do it like this ? it don't really looks clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-click` directive should not contain `{{}}` interpolation directive, also you should have `ng-model` on the `checkbox`  so that the value of item will updated, there is not need to call `toggleSelection` either

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-value="item.value" id="{{item.name}}"
     ng-click="item.selected!=item.selected" ng-model="item.selected"/>
</div>
```

Then if you want how many items are selected, for that you could use `filter` like `{{(items|filter: {selected: true}: true)}}` this will give you the items which are selected on html

**Markup**

```
<body class="container" ng-app="firstApp" ng-controller="EmpController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-value="item.value" id="{{item.name}}" 
     ng-click="item.selected!=item.selected" ng-model="item.selected" />
       {{item.name}}
  </div>
  {{items|filter:{selected: true}: true}}
</body>
```

[**Plunkr Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GgE1kdBaSR1FNdOn7WDt?p=preview)

**OR**

If you wanted use those selected element in controller then you could use `$filter` object inside controller, like `$filter('filter')($scope.items, {selected: true}, true)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.variables = [];
$scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(id) {
    if($scope.variables.length >= 2){
        $scope.variables[0] = $scope.variables[1];
        $scope.variables[1] = id;
    } else {
        $scope.variables.push(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you mean $scope.variables.lenght and scope.variables.push ?